# my iframe video playing wrong video

Tags: html, iframe

iam used this code for my little project using local host xampp:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
width="580" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2KkRwefwns0"
frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

for video in this link http://youtu.be/2KkRwefwns0

but in my local host the iframe going to this link http://youtu.be/ZnuwB35GYMY

[update]
okay. somehow its worked..

when i first try localhost to test my website my internet connection was bad but when today i try again in localhost my internet connection was great and the iframe working like magic

why?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: <div id=content>
  <article class=blog>     
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
    width="580" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2KkRwefwns0"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen>
    </iframe>   
  </article>
 </div>   hmm... like this?